# AngularJs : How to declare an app & multiple controllers, serves, etc, using an IFFE?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, iife

John Papa's famous [Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#iife) says to use IIFEs, to avoid the likes of  `var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);`
 and polluting the global namespace.

The example given is:

### logger.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('logger', logger);

    function logger() { }
})();
```

### storage.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('storage', storage);

    function storage() { }
})();
```

How does this work? Do I not need to declare the module at least once? E.g with `angular.module('app',[]);` (wrapped in an IIFE? (instead of `var app = angular.module('app',[]);` to avoid a global variable))?

However, the two usages of `angular.module('app')` in the example , do not declare, but will then ***evaluate*** `angular.module('app')` twice, which surely cannot be A Good Thing (in fact, I read a highly upvoted S.O. question earlier which said that this is A Bad Thing, and that there should be a single reference - but that would be a global, which is also A Bad Thing).

Which is it to be? Or can I declare my `angular.module('app')`, plus a few controllers, serves, factories, directives, in separate files, ***in separate IIFEs***? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I not need to declare the module at least once?

Yes, the module needs to be created with dependencies first:

### app.js

```
angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);
```

This must be done before any subsequent scripts add to it. It need not be enclosed in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) because it doesn't declare any global variables.

To avoid pollution of the global namespace, the following needs to be enclosed in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

### logger.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('logger', logger);

    function logger() { }
})();
```

---

### On the other hand

### storage.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
.service('storage', function storage() {
    var value;
    this.get = function() { return value; };
    this.set = function(val) {
        value = val;
    };
})
```

This does not need an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) because it does not declare any global variables or functions.

Both examples avoid polluting the global namespace.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS angular.module Method API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module#overview)

Answer (score 1):

`angular.module('app')` without array as 2nd param is a getter, it is ok to use it multiple times.

To improve this you need some build tool, e.g. we use webpack (it will wrap everything into IIFE for u btw) and now it looks like this:

logger.js :

```
export default ['$log', function($log) {}]
```

storage.js :

```
export default ['$http', function($http) {}]
```

module.js :

```
import logger from './logger.js';
import storage from './storage.js';
angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('logger', logger)
        .factory('storage', storage);
```

Comment: Upvote, although you lost me at "`you need some build tool`" - they seem to add so much unnecessary stuph :-(

Comment: "`angular.module('app') without array as 2nd param is a getter, it is ok to use it multiple times`" - so why does John Papa's style guide say to use an IIFE?